# ANDROID STUDIO 4.0 ERROR(No progress at the end of opening stage)

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-studio-4.0

[androiderror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNw7s.jpg)

After installing Android Studio 4.0, JAVA_PATH etc. I have adjusted everything. But after coming to this stage, there is no progress at this point and the interface does not open. What do you recommend?

Comment: Reinstall android studio

Comment: I did an infinite number of what you said